# How can i set alert on gcp dataflow pipeline based on log pattern matching

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-monitoring

Let see, I want to notify with alert on Dataflow pipeline using log based.But in log based alert , i cant see any option if i have to set alert on particular pattern matching like, if in log any message "Job failed due to ....", here i want to trigger an alert based on condition like "job failed *". . It should alert me if any message in log occur. Highly appreciated your help

I tried Dataflow-log entries option, but didnt get anything on pattern matching log.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonPayload.message=~"some pattern"

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language